# Printing Ember.js page : templates not displaying

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I try to print my Ember.js page application, templates aren't displayed on the sheet (it only displays a big empty white section). Any explanations or solutions?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use traditional media queries to implement the ability to print from your Ember app. As far as I am aware there, no one has created an ember addon to support print functionality at this time. ([See here](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/2958) where it doesn't look like anyone has a good suggestion for a similar question.) I can imagine it would be difficult to support generic functionality for printing that looks decent across apps, which may explain why no one has attempted to create an add on at this time.